# get last succesfully built commitId returns commitId of library instead of current job

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I am building a library function to get the commit_id of the last successful build in Jenkins (to determine a list of changed files since that commit).

```
def getLastSuccessfulSHA1() { 
  def b = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
  if(b == null) {
    return ""
  }
  return b.getAction(hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData.class).getLastBuiltRevision().getSha1String()
```

}

The code above is in a separate git repo, let's call it 'library'. This repository is loaded into Jenkins using `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Pipeline Libraries`

When I create a new Pipeline job and execute the following code:

```
def b = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
echo b.getAction(hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData.class).getLastBuiltRevision().getSha1String()
```

I am getting the following result:

```
Started by user Doedens, Harm
Loading library pipeline_utils@master
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to git@git:foo/jenkins-pipelines.git
> git config remote.origin.url git@git:foo/jenkins-pipelines.git # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
> git --version # timeout=10
> git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> git rev-parse master^{commit} # timeout=10
> git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> git config remote.origin.url git@git:foo/jenkins-pipelines.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@git:foo/jenkins-pipelines.git
> git --version # timeout=10
> git fetch --tags --progress git@git:foo/jenkins-pipelines.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
Checking out Revision 00ea6f0fa0eaed45f06cdb695b955e22b96b4e25 (master)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 00ea6f0fa0eaed45f06cdb695b955e22b96b4e25
> git rev-list 00ea6f0fa0eaed45f06cdb695b955e22b96b4e25 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] echo
00ea6f0fa0eaed45f06cdb695b955e22b96b4e25
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

This is weird because the commit_id it produces is coming from the utils git repo not the Git repo associated with the job. In fact I have not configured a Git repo on the job yet...

**EDIT:** explained/simplified question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Actionable.html#getAction-java.lang.Class-) the `getAction` method:

> Gets the action (first instance to be found) of a specified type that
>   contributed to this build.

Because Jenkins loads a library as the very first Action of this build, that Action will be returned with the corresponding details. If you want the Revision of the Git repo you're interested in you have filter that Action like so:

```
def b = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
def actions = b.getActions(hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData.class)
for(action in actions) {
    if(action.getRemoteUrls().contains('git@git:foo.git')) {
        return action.getLastBuiltRevision().getSha1String()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scripr SH in linux to get the last commit in GIT.

Here is the code

`git log --pretty="%h/%ad - %s. By %cn" --no-merges --since="$DATE" >> //logs/historic_git.log`

Comment: Thanks, but: I want the commit of the last successful build in Jenkins, not the last commit since a specific date

Answer (score 0):

Need to add toString() to Harm Doedens proposal to work

```
def b = currentBuild.rawBuild.getPreviousSuccessfulBuild()
def actions = b.getActions(hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData.class)
for(action in actions) {
    if(action.getRemoteUrls().toString().contains('git@git:foo.git')) {
        return action.getLastBuiltRevision().getSha1String()
    }
}
```